# How to get the ValueMember of an item in a Listbox for a given index number?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, listbox, valuemember

I have a `ListBox` which holds a`DisplayMember` called "Data" and a `ValueMember` called "Number". I want to get the `ValueMember` of all the items using a loop as following.

```
for (int i = 0; i < ListBox1.Items.Count; i++)
{ 
    //Get the `ValueMember` of `Item` where it's `Index` is `i` 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you tried like code below:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ListBox1.Items.Count; i++)
{ 
   Console.WriteLine((ListBox1.Items[i] as YourItemClassType).Number.ToString());
}
```

`YourItemClassType`  is your class that you adding to ListBox1, `YourItemClassType` contains Number and Data properies

Hope helps

Comment: Console.WriteLine with ListBox?

Comment: @TalhaIrfan ConsoleWriteLine will print to your OutPut window if you are using Visual studio, also it is for testing, you can show it any where for example in message box

Comment: Did you mean Debug.WriteLine?

Comment: @TalhaIrfan Does not matter, I'm using Console to quick look at output window